# Why does MySQL give me "ERROR 114 - Table Full"?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MySQL database table with 31,107,600 rows in it.
It's using InnoDB.
This is on a CentOS 7 system.

The table has these columns:

- id
- timestamp
- mac
- data
- direction
- site_id

I want to create an index, so I run this command:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD INDEX idx_my_index (mac, site_id, timestamp);
```

It takes about 30 seconds, and then gives me this:

```
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'MY_TABLE' is full
```

My MySQL is using the default `/var/lib/mysql` to store its data. Currently, the partition that folder is on has 12GB free, and my database is only 2.7 GB in size, so as far as I can tell, it should have more than enough space.

Why am I seeing this error? Online searches show that perhaps it is using a temporary table, and hitting restrictions on the size of the temporary table? Could it be that? Or something else? How can I confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

While the ALTER TABLE statement is running, observe your space usage on all file systems using df. See if space on another file system, particularly a small one, is rapidly decreasing, e.g. if you have /tmp on tmpfs.